# Why doesnt to_string() work for my pandas calculation?

Tags: python, pandas

```
def total_incidents_created(self):
    df = pd.read_csv("poam.csv", encoding='windows-1252', parse_dates=True)
    df = df.Completed.value_counts().Assigned
    df = df.to_string()
    print(df)
```

i keep getting an error AttributeError:
numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'to_strin

the variable has an integer 10 assigned to it...

Comment: You write `assigned.to_string()` but most probably `assigned` is not a pandas DataFrame.

Comment: assigned was the new variable name....

Comment: in that case do you want to convert `df.Completed.value_counts().Assigned` to a string? Better give a sample of your `poam.csv`, because so far we can just speculate.

Comment: yes, .assigned is just a column name in the dataset

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for something like the following and seems also that your mistake was to write `df.value_counts.assigned.to_string()`, instead of `df.assigned.value_counts().to_string()`

```py
import pandas as pd
# This will be a small DataFrame example with an 'assigned' column
df = pd.DataFrame(([0,'zero'], [1, 'one'], [2,'one']), columns=['col', 'assigned'])

df.head()
Out[22]: 
   col assigned
0    0     zero
1    1      one
2    2      one

# the output of value_counts()
df.assigned.value_counts()
Out[23]: 
one     2
zero    1
Name: assigned, dtype: int64

# The above output converted to string
df.assigned.value_counts().to_string()
Out[24]: 'one     2\nzero    1'

# and the above printed
print(df.assigned.value_counts().to_string())
one     2
zero    1
```